# Highcharts rose diagram with json

Tags: json, highcharts

I've got a php script (data.php) that is returning the following json data from a mysql database:

```
[[0,0.35,0,1.05,1.05,0.7,0.35],
 [0,0.7,0,1.05,1.74,1.74,0],
 [0,2.09,0,0.7,2.09,1.05,0.35],
 [0.35,1.74,0,1.05,1.05,1.05,0.35],
 [0.7,0.7,0,1.05,1.74,1.05,0.35],
 [0,1.05,0,2.09,2.09,1.39,0.7],
 [0,1.39,0,1.39,0.7,1.39,0.7],
 [1.05,1.05,0,1.05,0.35,1.05,0.35],
 [0,1.39,0,0.7,0.7,0.35,0.7],
 [0.35,0.7,0,0.7,0.35,1.39,0.7],
 [0,2.09,0,1.05,1.74,1.05,0],
 [0,1.05,0,1.05,1.05,0.7,0.35],
 [0.35,1.05,0,1.74,1.74,1.39,0.35],
 [0,1.05,0,1.39,1.74,1.05,0.35],
 [0,1.39,0,1.39,0.7,0,0.35], 
 [0,0,0,1.74,2.09,0.35,0.35]]
```

I am now trying to use that data with a highcharts rose chart example but am struggling to work out got to get the data displayed.

Any highchart/json experts care to assist?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar-wind-rose/)

Comment: What's the matter? U getting any errors?

Comment: Im not getting any data displayed on the page, but then again I dont think Ive taken the example and converted it to work with json correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse your data and return each rows as simple series, to achive this figure:

```
series: [{
        data: [0, 0.35, 0, 1.05, 1.05, 0.7, 0.35]
    },{
        data: [0, 0.7, 0, 1.05, 1.74, 1.74, 0],
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ky4g/1/